# Rails - JOIN clause doesn't include row with null Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, squeel

Let's say I have this data (notice the null `author_id` in third book):

```
     Authors
-------------------------
  id  |  name
-------------------------
  1   |  Susan Collins
  2   |  Steven Meyer
-------------------------

   Books
--------------------------------------
 id  |  author_id  |  title
--------------------------------------
 1   |      1      |  Hunger Games
 2   |      2      |  Twilight
 3   |     nil     |  Games of Throne
--------------------------------------
```

I have a search bar for Books. I want it to be searchable by Book's title and Author's name.

For example when I search for "Susan". It will return books are titled like "Susan" or authored by name like "Susan".

**The problem is**: When I search for "Game", it only returns "Hunger Games". It doesn't select "Game of Throne" because the `author_id` is null.

I made the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21f64/2) here.

This is the SQL generated from my Rails code:

```
SELECT books.* FROM books
  INNER JOIN authors ON authors.id = books.author_id
  WHERE (
    ( LOWER(books.title) LIKE LOWER("%game%") )
    OR
    ( LOWER(authors.name) LIKE LOWER("%game%") )
)
```

And the *result* only returns 1 row: "Hunger Games". No "Game of Thrones".

Is there a way to include the row with null Foreign Key?

I will accept SQL query as answer, I will try to figure out the Rails code myself.

Thanks

[EDIT]

Here's the Rails code that generate the SQL: (I use **Squeel** gem)

```
search = "%#{params[:search]}%" # the query is taken from param

Books.joins(:author).where {
  ( lower(title) =~ lower(search) ) |
  ( lower(author.name) =~ lower(search) )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation? And what should the MySQL result set look like?

Comment: yes, I already convert the case using `LOWER`, so the case doesn't matter. The SQL Result just returns "Hunger Games". I will add it to the edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` : 
http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Replace left by inner in your Sql Fiddle and you will get the books with and without authors.

In rails you can have a left join by replacing `joins` by `includes`. Because it keeps data from the first table without relations, it is often used when you want to eager load relations to prevent the N+1 query problem.

Comment: Wow thanks! never properly learn SQL before. So I don't really know about this LEFT RIGHT INNER join.

Comment: I think that particular resource is rather frowned upon within SO (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource)

Comment: Changed it to the only other English link I could find. I guess this one should be OK on SO ^^ http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're after...

```
SELECT b.* 
  FROM books b
  LEFT
  JOIN authors a
    ON a.id = b.author_id
   AND a.name LIKE '%game%'
 WHERE b.title LIKE '%game%';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I have to select the answer by @Syl because he/she answered it first.